# Emoji insertion in latex pdf

Tags: symbols, input-encodings

Here is my code in latex file

```
   \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
   \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
   \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
   \smartqed
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \section{Introduction}
    painted nails () to a slightly whimsical ghost ()
   \end{document}
```

I am getting errors -

```
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.112 ...rything from a set of painted nails (
                                                  )
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: We can't help you without a minimal working example (MWE). Please, add the code that presents the issue.

Comment: This package could be helpful: https://github.com/henningpohl/latex-emoji?files=1